# Cleaning the exterior of a Cuckoo clock

Tags: restoration, clean-up

I am trying to restore an old Cuckoo clock. It hasn't been cleaned for a while and it has a layer of grime and dust on top (so dusting it only is not an option). What is the best product to get the grime out of it without damaging the wood?

[image: cuckoo clock]

Comment: Is it "grime" ?  or just the patina or fading that comes with age. Be careful and do your research before doing anything. Does it have value, monetary or sentimental.  You may look into Howard products, https://www.howardproducts.com/products/

Comment: there's a bit of everything. Some blackish grime in corners, fading and other bits have a thinner layer of dust. It also needs to be varnished or oiled as the wood feels dry, exposed.

Comment: I'm not sure WW.SE is the right place for this. I mean, folks here will have lots of experience with wood, but restoration is a much different beast. Even woodworkers who restore tools will often make them usable, not museum pieces. That being said, I'm not sure anything other than patience and spotting with warm water is advised. I sort of feel like you ought to consult an expert, not the SE hivemind...

Comment: I totally agree with you @jdv and I had the same thought and found this forum https://mb.nawcc.org/forums/clock-case-restoration-and-repair.32/. I'll leave this question open just in case but I might answer it as I get more information from this other forum.

Comment: There are multiple approaches you could use here, each with its own pros and cons. At the end of the day what you end up doing is pretty much down to the individual. Even armed with the same full repertoire of techniques a dozen people faced with a similar project might choose 6 or 7 different methods between them. Just to note, one of those approaches would be to dust it (using small brushes as needed) and *nothing* else.

Comment: I get what you mean but the idea is to restore it closer to new. The damage is beyond old charm. There are even a couple of bits that have parts rotten.